# Error al ejecutar listFiles() en conexion FTP de Java

Tags: java, ftp

estoy intentando listar los archivos en una conexion de java a un servidor FTP y no hay forma.

El código és el siguiente:

```
clientFtp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
            FTPFile[] ftpFiles = clientFtp.listFiles();
            for (FTPFile ftpFile : ftpFiles) {
                // Check if FTPFile is a regular file
                if (ftpFile.getType() == FTPFile.FILE_TYPE) {
                    System.out.printf("FTP");
                }
            }
```

Y el error que me reporta és:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
The import org.apache.oro cannot be resolved
The import org.apache.oro cannot be resolved
The import org.apache.oro cannot be resolved
The import org.apache.oro cannot be resolved
The import org.apache.oro cannot be resolved
The import org.apache.oro cannot be resolved
Pattern cannot be resolved to a type
MatchResult cannot be resolved to a type
PatternMatcher cannot be resolved to a type
_matcher_ cannot be resolved
Perl5Matcher cannot be resolved to a type
pattern cannot be resolved
Perl5Compiler cannot be resolved to a type
MalformedPatternException cannot be resolved to a type
result cannot be resolved or is not a field
_matcher_ cannot be resolved
pattern cannot be resolved or is not a field
result cannot be resolved or is not a field
_matcher_ cannot be resolved
result cannot be resolved or is not a field
result cannot be resolved or is not a field
result cannot be resolved or is not a field
result cannot be resolved or is not a field
result cannot be resolved or is not a field
result cannot be resolved or is not a field
result cannot be resolved or is not a field

at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.parser.RegexFTPFileEntryParserImpl.<init>(RegexFTPFileEntryParserImpl.java:19)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.parser.ConfigurableFTPFileEntryParserImpl.<init>(ConfigurableFTPFileEntryParserImpl.java:57)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.parser.UnixFTPEntryParser.<init>(UnixFTPEntryParser.java:136)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.parser.UnixFTPEntryParser.<init>(UnixFTPEntryParser.java:119)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.parser.DefaultFTPFileEntryParserFactory.createUnixFTPEntryParser(DefaultFTPFileEntryParserFactory.java:169)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.parser.DefaultFTPFileEntryParserFactory.createFileEntryParser(DefaultFTPFileEntryParserFactory.java:94)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.initiateListParsing(FTPClient.java:2359)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.listFiles(FTPClient.java:2142)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.listFiles(FTPClient.java:2188)
```

La conexion funciona bien y si modifico el código por este otro el listado me funciona perfectamente:

```
String[] filesFTP = clientFtp.listNames();
            int count = 1;
            // Executem un for per llistar tots els arxius
            for (String file : filesFTP) {
                System.out.println("File " + count + " :" + file);
                count++;
            }
```

Entiendo que el error está en el uso de la funcion listFiles pero no hay forma. Alguna ayuda? Gracias!

Archivo pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>Eac1</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
   <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
   <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.3.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-ri</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.3</version>
</dependency>
 </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: ¿Puedes por favor adjuntar tu pom? ¿Qué versión de java estás usando? ¿Qué versión de Apache Commons Net estás usando? Tiene que ser una bien vieja (<= 1.4.1 ) porque es que Apache Commons desde la versión 2.0 no depende de `oro` y ya van por la versión 3.8.0.

Comment: ¿Se puede saber de donde importas las dependencias de FTP? ¿Agregaste el tú el jar manual? En tu pom no están.